# Unable to write file on HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have installed hadoop-2.6.0 and also I checked that all the hadoop daemons are running. I am able to create or copy directory in hdfs but not able to copy file to hdfs.

**Command:**

```
bin/hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/130853/Hadoop_Data/abc /trial/abc
```

**It's giving following exception:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCrc32.nativeComputeChunkedSumsByteArray(II[BI[BIILjava/lang/String;JZ)V
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCrc32.nativeComputeChunkedSumsByteArray(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCrc32.calculateChunkedSumsByteArray(NativeCrc32.java:86)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.DataChecksum.calculateChunkedSums(DataChecksum.java:430)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSOutputSummer.writeChecksumChunks(FSOutputSummer.java:202)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSOutputSummer.flushBuffer(FSOutputSummer.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSOutputSummer.flushBuffer(FSOutputSummer.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.close(DFSOutputStream.java:2217)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:106)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:112)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.CommandWithDestination$TargetFileSystem.writeStreamToFile(CommandWithDestination.java:466)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.CommandWithDestination.copyStreamToTarget(CommandWithDestination.java:391)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.CommandWithDestination.copyFileToTarget(CommandWithDestination.java:328)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.CommandWithDestination.processPath(CommandWithDestination.java:263)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.CommandWithDestination.processPath(CommandWithDestination.java:248)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processPaths(Command.java:306)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processPathArgument(Command.java:278)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.CommandWithDestination.processPathArgument(CommandWithDestination.java:243)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processArgument(Command.java:260)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processArguments(Command.java:244)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.CommandWithDestination.processArguments(CommandWithDestination.java:220)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.CopyCommands$Put.processArguments(CopyCommands.java:267)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processRawArguments(Command.java:190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.run(Command.java:154)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.run(FsShell.java:287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.main(FsShell.java:340)
```

Can someone please help on this?

Comment: The question formatting is of really low quality.

Comment: Hi, StackOverflow is for code-oriented questions, maybe you will be more successful asking at [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) or [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 0):

what is  your Linux System ? 64bit or 32 bit ?

if it's 64bit , suggest you  recomplie  hadoop source code  in order to it support native lib .

if it's 32bit ,suggest you switch 64bit system.

try execute  command , 
`hadoop checknative -a`

[image]

Comment: I am using 64bit linux. After executing this command, found all true except 'openssl' (openssl: false Cannot load libcrypto.so )